# UISegmentedControl works on iPhone but not iPad?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I use a UISegmentedControl, with 2 segments that spans the width of the screen.[image]

This works as expected on iPhone. Tapping cat mode switches the highlight to cat mode, and the appropriate functions take place. However, on iPad, tapping Cat Mode does nothing. No highlight switch, no functions. If I start the highlight on Cat Mode, the same thing happens in reverse (all good on iPhone, Dog Mode can't be selected on iPad).

I use obviously one storyboard for both iPhone and iPad with Autolayout, and I'm not varying anything related to this segmented control for traits, so I have no clue what's going on. All other functions perform properly on iPhone and iPad.

Please let me know if I can provide additional info to help solve this question.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can't tap on a segment, that suggests that something is wrong with your layout constraints, such that either (1) something is covering the segmented control, or (2) the segmented control is larger than its superview. You can investigate by using the wonderful View Debugger included with Xcode. It is impossible to help you further from here; you can see your project, we can't.

Comment: (1) a hidden google ad banner decided it wanted to cover the segmented control for the first time. thanks for the tip about view debugger-- it's really neat!

Comment: Great that the problem is solved. I suggest you either answer your own question (could be useful) or delete it.

Comment: Done, thanks @matt for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a Google Ad Banner blocking it. View debugger helped me see that. Thanks @matt for the suggestion to try it.